# ToRequestContext method missing in servicestack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, servicestack, mod-mono

Using some examples I am attempting to get SS authentication working in an asp.net MVC application. I am using this line:

```
authService.RequestContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequestContext();
```

No matter what I do, I cannot find "ToRequestContext". I believe I've added the proper using:

```
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpContext.ToRequestContext()` extension method lives in [ServiceStack.HttpExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack/HttpExtensions.cs#L15), so the correct namespace would be just:

```
using ServiceStack;
```

Comment: Funny enough - this was the first line in the .cs file. Cleaning the project and restarting VS10 a few times resolved it. I feel like an idiot now